# How to solve array index out of bounds exception for hashmap string split in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to put a text file into a hashmap with a while loop, and use string split to get the key value pairs. However, I keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Extract {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Extract e = new Extract();
        HashMap<String, String> x = e.hashFile("locations.txt");
        x.get("name");

    }

    public HashMap<String, String> hashFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        String line;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            line = in.nextLine();


            String[] keyvalue = line.split(":");
            keyvalue[1] = keyvalue[1].trim();


            data.put(keyvalue[0], keyvalue[1]); // this is where the exception is thrown from

        }


        in.close();
        return data;


    }


}
```

My text file locations.txt looks like :

```
name: Starting Point Park
exits: 1
exitDirection: E
description: You were just given your first cell phone as a birthday-present and you are at the park taking selfies. You choose your best-looking photo and upload it to your brand-new Instagram account. Suddenly, a white rabbit runs up and steals your phone and heads down a hole just big enough for you to fit in to. Instantly you panic and worry about the lost phone, not because it was a gift, but because you need to see how many likes your photo got.
```

Comment: Have you looked in the debugger (or tried printing to the console) the value of `line` in the iteration where it fails? (I suspect it *actually* fails on the line before, when you use `keyvalue[1] = keyvalue[1].trim();`.)

Comment: It does fail on the line with data.put(), Ive tried deleting the trim line to see if it would run without it but it still fails

Comment: Well yes, if you delete the `trim()` line it'll still fail on the following line - but *with* the `trim()` line in, it'll fail on the `trim()` line, because that's where you first access `keyvalue[1]` which is invalid in this case.

Comment: I added sout to the loop and it prints the key values 0 and 1 fine, I don't understand why this won't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the exact code you've got here and the file content you've stated. I *can* reproduce the exception if the `locations.txt` file contains another line such as "no colon here". Please add logging for the whole of `line`, e.g. `System.out.println("Value of line is '" + line + "'");` (straight after you've read the line) and then include that output in the question. I strongly suspect that that output will explain what's going on (which is why I asked about the value of `line` on the problematic iteration in the first comment).

Comment: I think I found the issue, the file I'm using also has a  key description: followed by several sentences describing the location. Once I deleted that from the file it works fine. So now I need to find a way to split a key and several sentences .

Comment: Right. Before you actually fix the problem, however, it would be worth looking back at the earlier comments - I gave you steps that would have helped you find that problem earlier, but you kept asserting that it should be fine, and that the `trim()` line wasn't failing (when it really would). I'd strongly advise that you use this situation to improve your diagnostic skills, to help you find the problem yourself more quickly next time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe a hashmap isn't the best data structure to use when I have multiple strings for 1 key.

Comment: I don't know why yours throw exception. I copied the same code and it works fine. I'm getting the desired output. No errors.

Comment: Show the complete text of what was in locations.txt. I don't think your code has any errors for the file you've shown in question. It works fine on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following to see what is going on?  Catch the exception and print the string and the array.

```
        String[] keyvalue = null;
        try {
           keyvalue = line.split(":");
           keyvalue[1] = keyvalue[1].trim();

           data.put(keyvalue[0], keyvalue[1]); // this is where the exception is thrown from
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("line = " + line);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(keyvalue));
        }
```

Comment: `keyvalue` isn't in scope in the catch block - you'd need to declare it beforehand.

Comment: Ugh.  I had modified my try block to include additional code and forgot to make the change.  Thanks!

Comment: I found that the issue was one of my key value pairs in the text was multiple lines of strings. Does anyone know how to adjust this so that the description key returns multiple lines of strings?